# validating html input in DOM before submitting in flask

Tags: javascript, python, flask, dom

I wish to validate input form using javaScript DOM before submitting using flask. The codes are shown below:

```
<form role="search" class="navbar-form nav-item" action="s" method="GET">
  <input
    type="text"
    id="search"
    placeholder="Search Course"
    class="form-control"
    name="search_string"
    value="{{ search_value }}"
  />
  <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
</form>
```

```
@main.route("/s", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    if request.method == 'GET' and 'search_string' in request.args:
        search_value = request.args.get('search_string')
        #clear session if no search 
        if search_value=="":
            session.clear()
        session['search']  = search_value
        search = "%{}%".format(session['search'])
        #save keyword in database
        saved_search = Keywords.query.filter_by(keyword = session['search']).count() # search if exist in database before saving
        if saved_search < 1:
            save_search = Keywords(keyword=session['search'])
            db.session.add(save_search)
            db.session.commit()
        #end save keyword in database  
        posts1 = Post.query.filter(Post.course_name.like(search)).count()
        posts = Post.query.filter(Post.course_name.like(search)).order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)       
        if posts1 >  0 and len(search_value)>0:
            flash('Search result for {}'.format(search_value), 'success')
            return render_template('search.html', posts=posts, search_value = search_value)
        else:
            flash('No search result found for {}'.format(search_value), 'danger')
            return redirect(url_for('main.index'))

    else:
        posts = Post.query.filter(Post.course_name.like("%{}%".format(session['search']))).order_by(Post.timestamp.desc()).paginate(page=page, per_page=10)
        return render_template('search.html', posts=posts)
```

Now how do I write a javascript code to ensure the input field ( search ) is validated in javascript before running the flask code: def search():

Comment: What validation do you need to apply to the input?

Comment: first you have to learn JavaScript and next you can write JavaScript code which you add directly in template `search.html`

Comment: @Mario I mean sanitizing input.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so you definitely want to do some form validation. Primarily, it will consist of some type of string formatting that is triggered on some type of event.

I've written a simple form validation web app using vanilla JS that does form validation that is reflected in the DOM, you can clone this repository and see it work on your own machine and play with it but it should cover what you need.

https://github.com/Daniel-Wh/jsFormExample

Comment: This is very useful. Thanks very much